# how to instantiate an StaxXmlPullParserFactory in android-8?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I keep getting below error message while trying to run simple app on emulator and I can't figure out why. Any help would be really appreciated:

2022-01-19 21:00:38.935 13581-13581/com.thecircle.circle_beta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.thecircle.circle_beta, PID: 13581
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.XmlPullParserFactory: Provider org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.stax.StaxXmlPullParserFactory could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:233)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:183)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:392)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.SmackXmlParser.getXmlPullParserFactory(SmackXmlParser.java:44)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.SmackXmlParser.newXmlParser(SmackXmlParser.java:65)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils.getParserFor(PacketParserUtils.java:80)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:159)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:154)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.(SmackInitialization.java:103)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Smack.getVersion(Smack.java:38)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Smack.ensureInitialized(Smack.java:64)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.(ConnectionConfiguration.java:115)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.java:64)
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.xmpp.XMPPHandler.connect(XMPPHandler.java:30)
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity.startXmppService(PhoneNumberActivity.java:62)
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity.access$400(PhoneNumberActivity.java:27)
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity$1.onClick(PhoneNumberActivity.java:53)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.stax.StaxXmlPullParserFactory.(StaxXmlPullParserFactory.java:30)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:388)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416) 
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.SmackXmlParser.getXmlPullParserFactory(SmackXmlParser.java:44) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.SmackXmlParser.newXmlParser(SmackXmlParser.java:65) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils.getParserFor(PacketParserUtils.java:80) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:159) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:154) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.(SmackInitialization.java:103) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Smack.getVersion(Smack.java:38) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Smack.ensureInitialized(Smack.java:64) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.(ConnectionConfiguration.java:115) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.java:64) 
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.xmpp.XMPPHandler.connect(XMPPHandler.java:30) 
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity.startXmppService(PhoneNumberActivity.java:62) 
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity.access$400(PhoneNumberActivity.java:27) 
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity$1.onClick(PhoneNumberActivity.java:53) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~aqFATXxhdyAHQijKIOYWXw==/com.thecircle.circle_beta-k5LiJXZwDyvcFdkQlSjhkw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~aqFATXxhdyAHQijKIOYWXw==/com.thecircle.circle_beta-k5LiJXZwDyvcFdkQlSjhkw==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.stax.StaxXmlPullParserFactory.(StaxXmlPullParserFactory.java:30) 
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:388) 
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416) 
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.SmackXmlParser.getXmlPullParserFactory(SmackXmlParser.java:44) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.SmackXmlParser.newXmlParser(SmackXmlParser.java:65) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils.getParserFor(PacketParserUtils.java:80) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:159) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:154) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.(SmackInitialization.java:103) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Smack.getVersion(Smack.java:38) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Smack.ensureInitialized(Smack.java:64) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.(ConnectionConfiguration.java:115) 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.java:64) 
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.xmpp.XMPPHandler.connect(XMPPHandler.java:30) 
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity.startXmppService(PhoneNumberActivity.java:62) 
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity.access$400(PhoneNumberActivity.java:27) 
at com.thecircle.circle_beta.PhoneNumberActivity$1.onClick(PhoneNumberActivity.java:53) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

I AM JUST RUNNING BELOW CODE:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Xml;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.android.AndroidSmackInitializer;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.XmlPullParser;
import org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException;

import java.io.IOException;


public class XMPPHandler extends AppCompatActivity {
    private XMPPTCPConnection connection;
    //private XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config;

    public void connect() throws IOException, InterruptedException, XMPPException, SmackException {

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setXmppDomain("192.168.1.9")
                .setHost("192.168.1.9")
                .setPort(5222)
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible)
                .build();
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();
    }

    //LOGIN
    public void login(String username, String password) throws XMPPException, InterruptedException, IOException, SmackException {
        if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
            connection.login(username, password);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Smack dependency declarations are probably wrong, as smack-xmlparser-stax is not used on Android (because there is no StAX parser in Android). Instead use smack-xmlparser-xpp3 in Android, which is a dependency of smack-android.

Comment: Thanks, I declared the smack dependency again and it worked for me.